# Is it possible in CkEditor or TinyMce to split the toolbar or menu bar from editor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, tinymce, richtextbox

I am using rich text editor ckeditor in my website which works fine but i want this to look something like a text editor used by blogger like shown in the image below. how is it possible?

[this is how i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N84a8.png)

Comment: You want vertical bar between editor tools. Right?

Comment: no, i want to separate the toolbar from the editor, make it wider than editor like shown in image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor 4.x you have the [sharedspace](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/sharedspace) plugin which allows you anchoring editor toolbar in specified element and use it for all editors you have on your web page.

You can find a demo of sharedspace plugin with source code here: https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sharedspace.html

About moving all toolbar items into a single line. Please open [standard](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-01-17-07-05/standard/samples/) or [full](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-01-17-07-05/full/samples/index.html) sample and play around with the `Toolbar Configurator`. If you remove row separators, you will get single line toolbar. Next you just need to copy the toolbar configuration and paste it into `config.js` (if you want to use it for all editors) or into editor instance configuration (if you want to use it for a single editor).

NOTE: The available space in that sample is too small to fit all the buttons in a single line but of course on your web page the available space may be wider.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get something similar to this if you use TinyMCE's inline mode. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/use-tinymce-inline/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the inline editing option for TinyMCE you can define a fixed location for its toolbar/menubar:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#fixed_toolbar_container

Based on your picture you can place it in a div that is located at the top of the page and it will appear there as opposed to "attached" the editor.